# Adding a disabled attribute to options from one select field based on the value in another select field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two select option fields--one with the ID of `determined` and the other `vehicle_type`.  Determined has 4 options--2 of which should disable the options in the vehicle_type select field.  I added an `alert()` if one of the 2 options are selected and the script fires as it should, but it will not add the `disabled` attribute.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#determined').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == 0 || $(this).val() == 3){
            alert('Yeah') /* This Works */
            $("#vehicle_type option[value='0']").prop('disabled',true);
        }else{
            $("#vehicle_type option[value='1']").prop('disabled',false);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select wire:model="determined" id="determined"
        name="determined">
    <option selected value>Please Select</option>
    <option value="0">Published HP Figure (DIN)</option>
    <option value="1">Measured with Dynojet+Dyno</option>
    <option value="2">Measured with Mustang Dyno</option>
    <option value="3">Measured with Engine Dynamometer Cell</option>
</select>

<select wire:model="vehicle_type" id="vehicle_type"
        name="vehicle_type">
    <option selected value>Please Select</option>
    <option value="0">Stick shift and 2WD vehicle</option>
    <option value="1">Automatic or 4WD Drive</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I'm confused, if selected value is 0 or 3 should it disable all the options or just some? also your code says you disable option 0 ,but enable option 1

Comment: Code snippet is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I disable all options as per your comment

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#determined').on("change", function() {
    const dis = $(this).val() == 0 || $(this).val() == 3;
    $("#vehicle_type option").prop("disabled",dis)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select wire:model="determined" id="determined" name="determined">
  <option selected value>Please Select</option>
  <option value="0">Published HP Figure (DIN)</option>
  <option value="1">Measured with Dynojet+Dyno</option>
  <option value="2">Measured with Mustang Dyno</option>
  <option value="3">Measured with Engine Dynamometer Cell</option>
</select>

<select wire:model="vehicle_type" id="vehicle_type" name="vehicle_type">
  <option selected value>Please Select</option>
  <option value="0">Stick shift and 2WD vehicle</option>
  <option value="1">Automatic or 4WD Drive</option>
</select>
```

but why not just hide?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#determined').on("change", function() {
    const dis = $(this).val() == 0 || $(this).val() == 3;
    $("#vehicle_type").toggle(!dis)
  }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select wire:model="determined" id="determined" name="determined">
  <option selected value>Please Select</option>
  <option value="0">Published HP Figure (DIN)</option>
  <option value="1">Measured with Dynojet+Dyno</option>
  <option value="2">Measured with Mustang Dyno</option>
  <option value="3">Measured with Engine Dynamometer Cell</option>
</select>

<select wire:model="vehicle_type" id="vehicle_type" name="vehicle_type">
  <option selected value>Please Select</option>
  <option value="0">Stick shift and 2WD vehicle</option>
  <option value="1">Automatic or 4WD Drive</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I have definitely been looking at this too long.  If 0 or 3 are selected in #determined, all options in #vehicle_type are to be disabled.

Comment: See updated script